# AWS CLI SSM get-parameters InvalidParameters on Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-ssm

I'm using

> GitBash v2.17.0
>
> AWS CLI v1.16.67
>
> Windows 10

**Problem**

I've created a `SecureString` parameter in the AWS SSM Parameter Store.  For sake of example, let's call the parameter

```
/levelOne/levelTwo
```

I'm trying to retrieve the parameter using the AWS CLI.  To do this I am using the following command:

```
aws ssm get-parameters --names '/levelOne/LevelTwo' --with-decryption
```

The problem is that the result returned is this:

[image]

As you can see, the parameter is being prefixed with `C:/Program Files/Git`.
Can anyone explain what I have done wrong please?

Thanks

Comment: Try using `Powershell` rather than `Git bash`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by [POSIX path conversion in MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion).

You can work around this by substituting // for the leading /, and then replacing the subsequent forward slashes with backslashes, e.g.

```
aws ssm get-parameters --names '//levelOne\levelTwo'
```

This command will only run correctly in MinGW, i.e. it will fail in Bash or Windows CMD.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue.
Check the region selected while you create the parameter store from the console.
The reason for this is that Aws-ssm is regional service.

```
aws ssm get-parameters --names "/levelOne/LevelTwo" --region us-west-1 --with-decryption
```

Answer (score 3):

i got it working by adding a space in front of the names parameter value. To get it working os independent.

```
aws ssm get-parameters --names " /levelOne/LevelTwo" --with-decryption
```